# Pandas error "***ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have..."

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an error when accessing data within a Pandas DataFrame *df*:

```
ipdb> df.loc[1988, 'ATTEND']
*** ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 1481 elements
```

1988 and 'ATTEND' are both in *df*:

```
ipdb> 1988 in df.index
True
ipdb> 'ATTEND' in df.columns
True
```

I have no idea what this error is about. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Example:

```
ipdb> df.iloc[21875:21880, 277:280]
      FUND  ATTEND  MAATTEND
1988     3       1         4
1988     2       3         0
1988     2       2         2
1988     2       2         7
1988     2       3         2

ipdb> df.loc[1988, 'ATTEND']
*** ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 1481 elements


GSSFilename = 'GSS Dataset/GSS7212_R2_copy.sav'
data = srw.SavReader(pathToData + GSSFilename)
df = pd.DataFrame(data.all(), index=data[:,0],    columns=ALL_VARIABLE_NAMES)
with data: 
    data = np.array(data.all())
```

**UPDATE**:
I think this problem was caused by two different Python instances accessing the same .sav file.

Comment: what version of pandas/numpy? pls post sample of frame and df.dtypes, df.info()

Comment: Can you locate the index and column position and extract a small subframe where this also fails using iloc?

Comment: @Jeff, all data types are float64. Numpy is 1.7.1, Pandas is 0.13.1

Comment: @AndyHayden, example:
ipdb> df.iloc[21875:21880, 277:280]
      FUND  ATTEND  MAATTEND
1988     3       1         4
1988     2       3         0
1988     2       2         2
1988     2       2         7
1988     2       3         2

ipdb> df.loc[1988, 'ATTEND']
*** ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 1481 elements

Comment: @Jeff, just updated Numpy to 1.8.1 and still get the same problem.

Comment: @DrMisha I can't replicate with the sub frame. Looks like a strange bug!

Comment: Can you post a link to the file and show how you read it in?

Comment: The file is pretty big: http://publicdata.norc.org/GSS/DOCUMENTS/OTHR/GSS_spss.zip

Comment: can you post exactly what you are doing from reading till the error?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, pressed "Enter" on that last comment prematurely. I'm trying out loading a file differently. Will report back asap.

Comment: This is a SPSS file, not sure how you go from their to a frame.

Comment: @Jeff, I use the savReaderWriter package. Updated my OP to show how I was doing it.

Trying to use the Stata version of the dataset, but it's taking a verrry long time to load

Comment: Pls make a version that is a csv that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this problem was caused by two different Python instances accessing the same .sav file

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the query I was using to populate the DataFrame was returning 0 rows because the database table was empty.  Once the table was populated, the error went away.